# error including Cplex library in cpp netbeans project

Tags: c++, netbeans-7, cplex

How can i add the cplex's library into my netbeans 7.4 cpp project?

I've tried to add inserting all the file path :

```
" #include "/Users/.../Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Preview1251/cplex/include/ilcplex/ilocplex.h""
```

but I still have error, the compiler said:

There are unresolved includes inside

```
"/Users/.../Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Preview1251/cplex/include/ilcplex/ilocplex.h""
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't use absolute paths to include files, set up your project such that `.../cplex/include` is in the *include search path*.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to put in your .h/.cxx code

```
#include "ilcplex/ilocplex.h"
```

Then in your project setting you add an include path so you get a flag -I pointing to {somewhere}/cplex/include

This will solve the compilation problem.

But you should also set the library by adding the library cplex1251.lib (check name) and the library path {somewhere}/cplex/lib/vs{number}/{variant}

May be you should have a look at the manual

[manual](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ibm.com%2Fdeveloperworks%2Fcommunity%2Fforums%2Fajax%2Fdownload%2F77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014819134%2F5b219cf2-1a5d-4a38-b630-7626bcbc0b5a%2Fattachment_14819134_Using_IBM_ILOG_CPLEX_Optimizers_with_Mic.htm&ei=o_sKVfOyB8TeOOudgLgL&usg=AFQjCNEdLSfVuMdV-ugp1kOiuzg6xupNFg&sig2=57IkOZ04lnzIApPn3s9Ucg&bvm=bv.88528373,d.ZWU&cad=rja), [IBM forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014606272#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014606272)